# Is this lock-free structure that guards usage of a single resource in Rust correct?

Tags: multithreading, rust, lock-free

I'm trying to make a structure that can marshal the use of a resource by multiple threads. I believe I have found a correct implementation, but I am still learning about memory orderings and such, so I want to make sure my reasoning is correct.

The resource cell has three operations (aside from creation):

- `try_acquire`, which attempts to take a mutable reference to the resource.
- `try_take`, which attempts to take the resource out, leaving the cell empty.
- `try_reserve`, which reserves space in an empty cell for a thread to place a new resource in.

In order to implement this, I created a struct containing an `UnsafeCell<Option<T>>` with three possible states.

```
const EMPTY: usize = 0;
const FULL: usize = 1;
const IN_USE: usize = 2;

pub struct ResourceCell<T: Send> {
    status: AtomicUsize,
    resource: UnsafeCell<Option<T>>,
}
```

Here's how I implemented the three operations:

```
pub fn try_acquire(&self) -> Result<Guard<T>, ()> {
    if self.status.compare_and_swap(FULL, IN_USE, Ordering::Acquire) == IN_USE {
        // A Guard allows mutable access to the resource for its lifetime
        // then when dropped, it calls status.store(FULL, Ordering::Release);
        return Ok(Guard(self))
    }
    Err(())
}

pub fn try_take(&self) -> Result<T, ()> {
    if self.status.compare_and_swap(FULL, IN_USE, Ordering::Acquire) == IN_USE {
        let value = self.resource.get().take().unwrap();
        self.cell.status.store(EMPTY, Ordering::Release);
        return Ok(value);
    }
    Err(())
}

pub fn try_reserve(&self) -> Result<Reserve<T>, ()> {
    if self.status.compare_and_swap(EMPTY, IN_USE, Ordering::Acquire) == IN_USE {
        // A Reserve has a single method that consumes itself and places a new 
        // value in the resource cell, then calls status.store(FULL, Ordering::Release);
        return Ok(Reserve(self))
    }
    Err(())
}
```

My reasoning that these are correct is as follows:

- For `try_acquire`, if the CAS sees `FULL`, then there must not exist any outstanding `Guard`s or `Reserve`s, because this `FULL` could only have originated from the dropping of a `Guard` or the consumption of a `Reserve` to set the value. Since both these operations specify `Ordering::Release`, this CAS synchronizes-with them, guaranteeing that this thread will also observe the accompanying write to the resource. The current state is also now `IN_USE`, which will prevent any operations on other threads from succeeding until the `Guard` is dropped. Therefore, no other thread will attempt to access the `UnsafeCell` until our `Guard` sets the state back to `FULL`, allowing it to safely access the `UnsafeCell`.
- `try_take` actually functions nearly identically to `try_acquire` except that after providing access to the `UnsafeCell`, it sets the state to `EMPTY` with `Ordering::Release`. I believe that this does not affect any of the reasoning in `try_acquire`.
- For `try_reserve`, if the CAS sees `EMPTY`, then there must not exist any outstanding `Guard`s or `Reserve`s, because this `EMPTY` either originated from the initial state of the cell, or from a previous successful call to `try_take`. Since `try_take` specifies `Ordering::Release`, this CAS synchronizes-with it, ensuring that this thread will really observe the resource as empty. The current state is also now `IN_USE`, which will prevent any operations on other threads from succeeding until the `Guard` is dropped. Therefore, no other thread will attempt to access the `UnsafeCell` until our `Reserve` sets the state back to `FULL`, allowing it to safely access the `UnsafeCell`.

Is this sufficient for thread-safety, or have I made an error?
[Here's a full code listing, including the implementations of `Guard` and `Reserve`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=829cfc32ef9d28f8053138131c1708b6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

const EMPTY: usize = 0;
const FULL: usize = 1;
const IN_USE: usize = 2;

pub struct ResourceCell<T: Send> {
    status: AtomicUsize,
    resource: UnsafeCell<Option<T>>,
}

impl<T: Send> ResourceCell<T> {
    pub fn new(data: Option<T>) -> ResourceCell<T> {
        ResourceCell {
            status: AtomicUsize::new(if data.is_none() { EMPTY } else { FULL }),
            resource: UnsafeCell::new(data)
        }
    }

    pub fn try_acquire(&self) -> Result<Guard<T>, ()> {
        if self.status.compare_and_swap(FULL, IN_USE, Ordering::Acquire) == IN_USE {
            return Ok(Guard(self, FULL)) 
        }
        Err(())
    }

    pub fn try_take(&self) -> Result<T, ()> {
        if self.status.compare_and_swap(FULL, IN_USE, Ordering::Acquire) == IN_USE {
            let value = unsafe { self.resource.get().as_mut().unwrap().take().unwrap() };
            self.status.store(EMPTY, Ordering::Release);
            return Ok(value);
        }
        Err(())
    }

    pub fn try_reserve(&self) -> Result<Reserve<T>, ()> {
        if self.status.compare_and_swap(EMPTY, IN_USE, Ordering::Acquire) == IN_USE {
            return Ok(Reserve(self))
        }
        Err(())
    }
}

unsafe impl<T: Send> Sync for ResourceCell<T> { }

pub struct Guard<'a, T: Send + 'a>(&'a ResourceCell<T>, usize);

impl<'a, T: Send + 'a> Guard<'a, T> {
    pub fn take(mut self) -> T {
        let value = unsafe { self.0.resource.get().as_mut().unwrap().take().unwrap() };
        self.1 = EMPTY;
        return value;
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Send + 'a> Drop for Guard<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.0.status.store(self.1, Ordering::Release);
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Send + 'a> Deref for Guard<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        return unsafe { self.0.resource.get().as_ref().unwrap().as_ref().unwrap() };
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Send + 'a> DerefMut for Guard<'a, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        return unsafe { self.0.resource.get().as_mut().unwrap().as_mut().unwrap() };
    }
}

pub struct Reserve<'a, T: Send + 'a>(&'a ResourceCell<T>); 

impl<'a, T: Send + 'a> Reserve<'a, T> {
    pub fn fill(self, value: T) {
        unsafe { *self.0.resource.get().as_mut().unwrap() = Some(value) };
        self.0.status.store(FULL, Ordering::Release);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know enough about rust to comment on the code, but https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be able to help too?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking `ResourceCell<T>` is essentially equivalent to `Mutex<Option<T>>`?

Comment: @trentcl Yeah, it's essentially the same except you don't have to lock it to tell if it's empty.